# Cabal repl won't run, "can't load .so/.DLL for: ..."

Tags: haskell, dll, sandbox, cabal, conduit

I am trying to get a project running that uses `conduit` and `conduit-extra`. This is the main module:

```
import Data.Conduit

main = do
    putStrLn "Done"
```

The cabal file requires base, conduit and conduit-extra:

```
...

build-depends:     base >=4.8 && <4.9,
                   conduit >=1.2.5 && <1.3,
                   conduit-extra >= 1.1.9.1 && <1.2
...
```

Yet when I run `cabal repl`,  this happens:

```
Johns-iMac:The-Project john$ cabal repl
Preprocessing executable 'The-Project' for The-Project-0.1.0.0...
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/exceptions-0.8.0.2/libHSexceptions-0.8.0.2-8GsEeHgaIks3pVGk6GaELJ-ghc7.10.2.dylib (dlopen(/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/exceptions-0.8.0.2/libHSexceptions-0.8.0.2-8GsEeHgaIks3pVGk6GaELJ-ghc7.10.2.dylib, 5): Library not loaded: @rpath/libHStransformers-compat-0.4.0.4-DCQioW2d4vYEa3T0AmFBPv-ghc7.10.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/exceptions-0.8.0.2/libHSexceptions-0.8.0.2-8GsEeHgaIks3pVGk6GaELJ-ghc7.10.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found)
```

I just completely reinstalled the Haskell Platform, and it's all sandboxed, so there shouldn't be any problems with competing dependencies.

What is happening, and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I deleted the sandbox (cabal.sandbox.config, .cabal-sandbox), and reinstalled the dependencies:

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal install --only-dependencies
cabal repl
```

We now have a new but very similar error:

```
Johns-iMac:The-Project john$ cabal repl
Preprocessing executable 'The-Project' for The-Project-0.1.0.0...
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/hashable-1.2.3.3/libHShashable-1.2.3.3-2GTZqecVp8NJZrNuKzGxfy-ghc7.10.2.dylib (dlopen(/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/hashable-1.2.3.3/libHShashable-1.2.3.3-2GTZqecVp8NJZrNuKzGxfy-ghc7.10.2.dylib, 5): Library not loaded: @rpath/libHStext-1.2.1.3-1l1AN4I48k37RaQ6fm6CEh-ghc7.10.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/hashable-1.2.3.3/libHShashable-1.2.3.3-2GTZqecVp8NJZrNuKzGxfy-ghc7.10.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found)
```

Comment: One thing that can make cabal go boom is if you fail to list one of your modules in the cabal file. This doesn't look likely to be the problem here, but I figured I'd mention it anyway. `cabal clean` is sometimes helpful, but it sounds like you've already tried more extreme measures. Another fairly extreme one is nuking your `.ghc` directory.

Comment: @dfeuer I did that about an hour ago with the haskell reinstall

Comment: @dfeuer - I [can reliably produce a "can't load .so/.DLL" error when a dependency fails to list a module in the cabal file](https://github.com/rampion/cabal-linking-bug), is that what you're talking about? And do you know if it already has a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

Given that this report refers to a problem loading hashable, and [the Github report](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/issues/225) refers to a problem loading exceptions, both of which are packages provided by the platform and not GHC, I have a feeling there's a problem with the platform installer. Can you try again with either [GHC for Mac OS X](https://ghcformacosx.github.io/) or [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack#readme) and see if it resolves the issue?

Note that, if you go the stack route, you'll want to run `stack init && stack build --install-ghc && stack ghci` in your project. In either case: you'll probably be safer if you completely remove the platform install first.

Comment: I completely removed the platform install, reinstalled it, new folder, new sandbox, newly reinstalled dependencies, same problem

Comment: Right. So I'm saying the problem may be the platform, and recommending you install something else. I've linked to two alternative installation methods